# Boost 1.73.0 asio has error when i use get_executor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

my ubuntu version is 20.04LTS and Boost version is 1.73
it's my code :

```
#include "server.h"
#include <iostream>

Server::Server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, unsigned short port)
    : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)) {
    start_accept();
}

void Server::start_accept() {
    tcp::socket socket(acceptor_.get_executor().context());
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket,
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
            handle_accept(std::move(socket), ec);
        }
    );
}

void Server::handle_accept(tcp::socket socket, const boost::system::error_code& error) {
    if (!error) {
        std::cout << "New connection accepted." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Error on accept: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
    start_accept();
}
```

in

```
tcp::socket socket(acceptor_.get_executor().context());
```

it always has error like `error: ‘class boost::asio::execution_context’ has no member named ‘get_executor’`

it's complete output

```
g++ -I include -std=c++17 -Wall -c src/server.cpp -o obj/server.o
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:24,
                 from include/server.h:4,
                 from src/server.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/io_object_impl.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::asio::detail::io_object_impl<IoObjectService, Executor>::io_object_impl(ExecutionContext&, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<ExecutionContext&, boost::asio::execution_context&>::value>::type*) [with ExecutionContext = boost::asio::execution_context; IoObjectService = boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>; Executor = boost::asio::executor; typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<ExecutionContext&, boost::asio::execution_context&>::value>::type = void]’:
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:132:20:   required from ‘boost::asio::basic_socket<Protocol, Executor>::basic_socket(ExecutionContext&, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<ExecutionContext&, boost::asio::execution_context&>::value>::type*) [with ExecutionContext = boost::asio::execution_context; Protocol = boost::asio::ip::tcp; Executor = boost::asio::executor; typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<ExecutionContext&, boost::asio::execution_context&>::value>::type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_stream_socket.hpp:112:47:   required from ‘boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<Protocol, Executor>::basic_stream_socket(ExecutionContext&, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<ExecutionContext&, boost::asio::execution_context&>::value>::type*) [with ExecutionContext = boost::asio::execution_context; Protocol = boost::asio::ip::tcp; Executor = boost::asio::executor; typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<ExecutionContext&, boost::asio::execution_context&>::value>::type = void]’
src/server.cpp:10:58:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/io_object_impl.hpp:87:40: error: ‘class boost::asio::execution_context’ has no member named ‘get_executor’
   87 |       implementation_executor_(context.get_executor(),
      |                                ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio/impl/execution_context.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/execution_context.hpp:409,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/scheduler.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/system_context.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/impl/system_executor.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/system_executor.hpp:129,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/associated_executor.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from include/server.h:4,
                 from src/server.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::initiate_async_accept::operator()(AcceptHandler&&, boost::asio::basic_socket<Protocol1, Executor1>*, boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::endpoint_type*) const [with AcceptHandler = Server::start_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>; Protocol1 = boost::asio::ip::tcp; Executor1 = boost::asio::executor; Protocol = boost::asio::ip::tcp; Executor = boost::asio::executor; boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::endpoint_type = boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp>]’:
/usr/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:152:49:   required from ‘static boost::asio::async_result<CompletionToken, Signature>::return_type boost::asio::async_result<CompletionToken, Signature>::initiate(Initiation&&, RawCompletionToken&&, Args&& ...) [with Initiation = boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::initiate_async_accept; RawCompletionToken = Server::start_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>; Args = {boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::executor>*, boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp>*}; CompletionToken = Server::start_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>; Signature = void(boost::system::error_code); boost::asio::async_result<CompletionToken, Signature>::return_type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:365:25:   required from ‘typename std::enable_if<boost::asio::detail::async_result_has_initiate_memfn<CompletionToken, Signature>::value, decltype (boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type, Signature>::initiate(declval<Initiation&&>(), declval<CompletionToken&&>(), (declval<Args&>)()...))>::type boost::asio::async_initiate(Initiation&&, CompletionToken&, Args&& ...) [with CompletionToken = Server::start_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>; Signature = void(boost::system::error_code); Initiation = boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::initiate_async_accept; Args = {boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::executor>*, boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp>*}; typename std::enable_if<boost::asio::detail::async_result_has_initiate_memfn<CompletionToken, Signature>::value, decltype (boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type, Signature>::initiate(declval<Initiation&&>(), declval<CompletionToken&&>(), (declval<Args&>)()...))>::type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:1351:75:   required from ‘auto boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::async_accept(boost::asio::basic_socket<Protocol1, Executor1>&, AcceptHandler&&, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Protocol, Protocol1>::value>::type*) [with Protocol1 = boost::asio::ip::tcp; Executor1 = boost::asio::executor; AcceptHandler = Server::start_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>; Protocol = boost::asio::ip::tcp; Executor = boost::asio::executor; typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Protocol, Protocol1>::value>::type = void]’
src/server.cpp:15:5:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:2434:7: error: static assertion failed: AcceptHandler type requirements not met
 2434 |       BOOST_ASIO_ACCEPT_HANDLER_CHECK(AcceptHandler, handler) type_check;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:1837:7: error: no match for call to ‘(Server::start_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>) (const boost::system::error_code&)’
 1837 |       BOOST_ASIO_CONNECT_HANDLER_CHECK(ConnectHandler, handler) type_check;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/server.cpp:12:9: note: candidate: ‘Server::start_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>’
   12 |         [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
      |         ^
src/server.cpp:12:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_context.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/io_context.hpp:861,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/io_object_executor.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/io_object_impl.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:24,
                 from include/server.h:4,
                 from src/server.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/non_const_lvalue.hpp:31:12: error: ‘boost::asio::detail::non_const_lvalue<T>::non_const_lvalue(T&) [with T = Server::start_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>]’, declared using local type ‘Server::start_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
   31 |   explicit non_const_lvalue(T& t)
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:36,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:24,
                 from include/server.h:4,
                 from src/server.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_service.hpp:419:8: error: ‘void boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service<Protocol>::async_accept(boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service<Protocol>::implementation_type&, Socket&, boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service<Protocol>::endpoint_type*, Handler&, const IoExecutor&) [with Socket = boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::executor>; Handler = Server::start_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>; IoExecutor = boost::asio::detail::io_object_executor<boost::asio::executor>; Protocol = boost::asio::ip::tcp; boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service<Protocol>::endpoint_type = boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp>]’, declared using local type ‘Server::start_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
  419 |   void async_accept(implementation_type& impl, Socket& peer,
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

i had try something like use make_shared, but it don't work...

Answer (score 1):

These interfaces do have changed slightly.

The good news is, you don't need all that. The idea of passing around execution contexts by reference is anti-pattern (since a long time) now. Instead, pass the executor - by value. It can decouple implementations from the particular type of execution context (system_context, thread_pool, io_context etc).

So at least change

```
tcp::socket socket(acceptor_.get_executor().context());
```

To

```
tcp::socket socket(acceptor_.get_executor());
```

#### Other Problems

You have [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you pass a reference to the local `socket` variable to an async operation.

You're also mixing overloads, because you are passing the `socket` by reference, but **ALSO** using the MoveAcceptHandler completion signature. That should not compile.

When we fix that, it already works for me with [Asio 1.16.1](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#boost_asio.history.asio_1_16_1___boost_1_73): https://compiler-explorer.com/z/EjvfPPeqr

```
void Server::start_accept() {
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket_, [this](error_code ec) { handle_accept(std::move(socket_), ec); });
}
```

[image]

### Simplify

Instead, embrace the MoveAcceptHandler! It will already do what you want, namely propagate the acceptor's executor to the new socket object.

Also removing the unnecessary `handle_accept` method:

```
struct Server {
    Server(asio::executor ex, uint16_t port) : acceptor_(ex, {{}, port}) { accept_loop(); }

  private:
    void accept_loop() {
        acceptor_.async_accept([this](error_code error, tcp::socket socket) {
            if (!error)
                std::cout << "New connection accepted: " << socket.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
            else
                std::cerr << "Error on accept: " << error.message() << std::endl;

            accept_loop();
        });
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << BOOST_ASIO_VERSION << "\n";
    asio::io_context ioc;

    Server s(ioc.get_executor(), 8989);

    ioc.run();
}
```

[image]

For more recent boost you'd use `any_io_executor` instead of `executor`.